# How to retrieve the colour list to set at run time

Tags: objective-c

I am new to I-Phone application development.I am facing an problem.

I like to change the colour of text at run time.

I have an button I like to retrieve all the colour option as an TableView.After choosing the colour from the table the colour of text should change automatically..

How to retrieve the colour list to enter the Colour Option in an Array for implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to get the list of colors automatically. You need to make an `NSArray` and fill it yourself with whichever colors you want. If you want to attach each color a name, either create a `class` (let's call this `NamedColor`) with `UIColor *color; NSString *name;` and add the `class` components into the array, or use `NSDictionary` (there are more options on doing this).

```
//somewhere in the init/viewDidLoad method
colors = [[NSArray alloc] init];
[colors addObject:[[[NamedColor alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor redColor] name:@"Red"] autorelease]];
//...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    textColor = ((NamedColor *)[colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).color;
}
```